# Mondrian composition with red, blue and yellow using HTML table

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help me to reproduce this painting in browser, with HTML `<table>` tag and CSS

The painting
[image: The painting]

I tried to do this task, but my teacher is not happy with the result, he says that, [those elements are need to be made from 1 table element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uND5I.png) but I have no idea how to utilize colspan and rowspan properly
this is my HTML for the table itself, I was not allowed to use anything else except tables, colspans, rowspans, and CSS.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

body {
  margin-top: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  empty-cells: show;
  border: 0px solid magenta;
  width: 404px;
  height: 404px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: 4px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.remove-border-left {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.remove-border-top {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

.remove-border-right {
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.remove-border-bottom {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.sm {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td class="remove-border-top remove-border-left" colspan="3">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-top" colspan="2">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-top yellow" colspan="3">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-top remove-border-right">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="remove-border-right remove-border-bottom">
    <td class="remove-border-left">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom red" colspan="4">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="yellow" colspan="3">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="remove-border-right remove-border-bottom">
    <td class="remove-border-left" rowspan="2">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="red" colspan="4">&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="remove-border-right sm">
    <td class="remove-border-right black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-right">&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-right">&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right sm">
    <td class="remove-border-left remove-border-bottom yellow">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom blue" colspan="3">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right red">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right sm">
    <td class="remove-border-left remove-border-bottom yellow">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom blue" colspan="3">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="remove-border-bottom remove-border-right red">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What specifically are the problems you're running into? The only problem I see are some truncated borders where there should be none. You may want to consider including the image next to the table in the snippet so that it's easier to compare them...

Comment: Looks like you did a pretty good job to me

Comment: I edited the question, my teacher says that such elements like red square, have to be made from 1 table element, not multiple, that's the problem, I have no idea how to make this with colspans and rowspans

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty darn close... You could tweak the sizes of the rows and columns a bit to make them line up better.

The biggest change I made was making the border classes additive rather than subtractive. Six of one, half dozen of the other, I guess. Just the way my brain works.

I also changed the colors to match those of the image, and added widths to the various columns.

I apologize if I missed commenting any of my additions/subtractions as I started getting into it I forgot to do that.

The real trick was, as you suspected, using `colspan` and `rowspan` judiciously.

Run the code snippet "full page" to see it properly.

```css
:root {
  --border-width: 6px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: floralwhite;
}

img {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  width: 404px;
  height: 404px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

table {
  empty-cells: show;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  width: 389px;
  height: 389px;
  margin: 6px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead { display: none }
tr {
  border: 0px none transparent;
}

td {
  border: 0px none transparent;
}

.bl {
  border-left: var(--border-width, 4px) solid black;
}

.bt {
  border-top: var(--border-width, 4px) solid black;
}

.br {
  border-right: var(--border-width, 4px) solid black;
}

.bb {
  border-bottom: var(--border-width, 4px) solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: #da422a;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #f8ce2e;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #3c5f99;
}

.sm {
  height: 40px;
}
.md {
  height: 58px;
}
.lg {
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table2">
  <col width="69"/>
  <col width="65"/>
  <col width="65"/>
  <col width="71"/>
  <col width="71"/>
  <col width="76"/>
  <col width="76"/>
  <col width="52"/>
  <tr class="md">
    <td class="br bb" colspan="3">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="br bb bl" colspan="2">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="br bb bl yellow" colspan="2">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bb bl">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lg">
    <td class="bt br bb">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br bb bl red" colspan="4" rowspan="2"><!-- added rowspan="2" -->&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br bb bl yellow" colspan="2">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lg">
    <td class="bt br bb" rowspan="2">&nbsp</td>
    <!-- removed cell -->
    <td class="bt br bb bl">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br bb bl">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sm">
    <td class="bt bb bb bl black" colspan="2" rowspan="2"><!-- added colspan="4" rowspan="2" -->&nbsp</td>
    <!-- removed cell -->
    <td class="bt bb bl">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt bb">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt bb bl">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br bb">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sm">
    <!-- removed cell -->
    <!-- removed cell -->
    <td class="bt br yellow" rowspan="2"><!-- added rowspan="2" -->&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt bl">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br bl blue" colspan="2" rowspan="2"><!-- added rowspan="2" -->&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt bl red" rowspan="2"><!-- added rowspan="2" -->&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sm">
    <!-- removed cell -->
    <td class="bt br bl" colspan="2"><!-- added colspan="2" -->&nbsp</td>
    <!-- removed cell -->
    <td class="bt bl black">&nbsp</td>
    <td class="bt br bl black">&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/84y4I.jpg" />
```